# Post an array into MySQL Workbench with Express.js api and mysql package

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

I'm working with Express.js and mysql package to create my apis, but i can't make a post.

This is my code so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const config = mysql.createConnection({
    host: theHost,
    port: thePort,
    user: theUser,
    password: thePass,        
    database: theDB,
});

const app = express();

config.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Success");

    } else {
        console.log("Error trying to connect");    
    }
});

app.get("/api/InternalAccess", function(req, res){
    config.query('SELECT * from InternalAccess', (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        res.send(result);
      });
});

app.post("/api/internalAccess", function(req, res){

    var info = { User: req.body.User, Password: req.body.Password, CreationDate: req.body.CreationDate };

    config.query('INSERT INTO InternalAccess SET ?', info, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        res.send(result);
      });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I have no problems with get, it works fine, but to make post from postman, i get the error: " Cannot read property "User" of undefined". Am i avoiding something? I'm really new using mysql package.

My db is MySQL Workbench, and as i said, i'm using Node.js, Express.js and mysql package.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have `req.body` populated automatically, you have to [use some body-parser middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body), like:

```
app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Of course, there can be multiple other causes (like, you're not constructing the request properly in postman), but the lack of setting the middlewares is the first place I'd fix.

Comment: Yeah! Was that... lotsa thanx. I owe you a beer

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `req.body` is null. I think you might just be missing the body-parser in your app.js.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

see other examples here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: well, Tudor was quicker than I.